# Windows IoT RPi3 Install Error

Tags: windows-iot, pi-3

I am unable to install Windows IoT on my RPi3.
I have signed up for insider and can start the download of the windows image but after it has downloaded about 500mb it fails with the message:
"windows 10 iot error executing partition setup script"
I have tried several times reformating the SD card and I have tried with 3 different SD cards but none will work.....